# Angular Material: How to apply <mat-error> message on tag <textarea>?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an application with Angular Material, in it I have a  field. I would like to know if it is possible to apply the  directive in this field as well as in the input fields. Here is my example of use.

```
  <mat-form-field>
    <textarea matInput placeholder="Textarea" minlength="5"></textarea>
    <mat-error>Feedaback message</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
```

The condition for firing the mat-error is the minLength applied to the tag.

Comment: Are you using reactive or template forms?

Comment: adding to that, are you using forms at all? `MatError` looks at either the `NgControl` applied to the input, which won't be applied unless it's part of an `NgForm` or has an `ngModel` binding, or the `ErrorStateMatcher` function which has to be supplied explicitly.

Comment: Yes, I am using reactive forms. I'll try use a function for validator, Thank you guys.